# EF 6 NotMapped attribute and fluent alternatives not working

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework

I have a C# .NET Framework 4.6.2 class library that uses Entity Framework 6.1.3. I have a property that is not mapped to the database and so have tried annotating it:

```
    [NotMapped]
    public MvcHtmlString AssignedToProjects { get; set; }
```

and as an alternative, used the fluent notation in the map class:

```
  Ignore(t => t.AssignedToProjects);
```

BTW I reverse engineered code-first from the database and this generates a map class that inherits from EntityTypeConfiguration<> that is called by the model builder.

The problem is that I get a "no mapping specified" error when the calling application (or integration test) is run against it.

Annoyingly the older VB.NET version of this project which uses .NET 4.5, EF 6.1.3 and a database-first (EDMX) approach works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there were a number of properties that weren't mapped (legitimately) by not marked as *Ignore/[NotMapped]*. It looks like database-first development (or perhaps in conjunction with VB.NET) doesn't need *Ignore/[NotMapped]*. 
I may have to write a tool to flag up non-mapped properties.